# Let Recycler View Items display their position in a text View

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, position

I have a recycler view which contains three text views, I would like one text view to function as a counter for each new item added to the recycler view. so the first item should display 1, the second item should display 2 etc. so far I've tried using the position, but it displays the total amount of positions for every item, meaning if there are 4 items in the recycler, it shows the position as 4 for all 4 of them.

the sets Text View is what should display the position.

this is the Adapter:

```
class TrackAdapter(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TrackAdapter.SetViewHolder>() {

private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
private var todayExercises = emptyList<WorkoutTable>() // Cached copy of words
var mName: String?=null

inner class SetViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val sets: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSets)
    val weight: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvWeight)
    val reps: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvReps)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):SetViewHolder {
    val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.track_item, parent, false)
    return SetViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SetViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val current = todayExercises[position]
    val sets = todayExercises.size   //attempt to get position for counter

    holder.sets.text = (sets.toString() + " set")  //this is where i tried setting the position
    holder.weight.text = (current.weight.toString() + " lbs")
    holder.reps.text = (current.reps.toString() + " reps")

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {




    }

}

internal fun setExercises(exercises: List<WorkoutTable>) {
    this.todayExercises = exercises
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}


override fun getItemCount() = todayExercises.size
```

}

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sets which you are reading **todayExercises.size**, you are asking for the list size. Instead just read the position

Comment: so i did like you said and did it this way:  var pos = position
      
        holder.sets.text = (pos.toString() + " set")     .... my problem now is, it starts from 0, how do i add 1 to make the first position 1? i tried just adding a +1 to the first variable, but it just adds it to the side to give me 01, 11, 21

Comment: ``position`` is an ``Int``, so add 1 to it before you convert it to a string (like ``val sets = position+1``)

Answer (score 0):

in your onBindViewHolder class in every textViews get Positions and increment it with nextInt like textView.get(position).nextInt(list.size())

Comment: I couldnt manage to get this to work, the "nextInt()" function is not recognized for some reason. or maybe im not inputing it properly.. can you have a look at the adapter and use the actual variable names, please?